# Service to service communication with authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, identityserver4

I am creating a service (web api) which is interacting with another service. I need to authenticate with this external service using IdentityServer.

I just wanted to confirm that for this it doesn't make sense to implement the refresh token since a webcontroller is constructed on a per request basis?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the implementation to be run as a singleton to improve performance of not always having to authenticate everytime I do a call (big performance hit) therefore the token needs to be actually renewed